# LDAP .ldif file understanding

Tags: linux, centos, ldap

i'm using LDAP server at a very beginner level, can't understand the .ldif file while creating a user. which objectclass allows which attributes? is there any list? also when two objectclass violates each other? i've tried RH423, but redhat books seems difficult to understand,any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Which objectclass allows which attributes? is there any list?

Yes. It's called a 'schema'. You need to look up the schema for the object classes you plan to use. It's all there.

> also when two objectclass violates each other?

This is not a question.

> i've tried RH423, but redhat books seems difficult to understand,any suggestion?

Suggestion for what?

Unclear what these secondary questions mean, if anything, but I've done my best with the main ones.